# Svelte can't seem to write data to variable after fetching from API

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, svelte

I've made myself an API which returns the following values:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Illmatic","artist":"Nas","songs":["The Genesis","N.Y. State Of Mind","The World Is Yours"],"offer":25.01,"offer_owner":123456,"due_date":1669593600000,"genre":"hiphop","auction_owner":696969}, 
{"id":2,"title":"Life After Death","artist":"The Notorious B.I.G.","songs":["Intro","Things Done Changed","Gimme The Loot"],"offer":25,"offer_owner":696969,"due_date":1669593600000,"genre":"hiphop","auction_owner":123456},
{"id":3,"title":"After Hours","artist":"The Weekend","songs":["Alone Again","After Hours","Save Your Tears","Escape From LA","Snowchild"],"offer":25,"offer_owner":123456,"due_date":1369593600000,"genre":"pop","auction_owner":696969}]
```

I have the following Svelte code:

```
import { onMount } from "svelte";

let albums;

onMount(async () => { 
fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/albums/").then((response) => response.json().then( 
(data) => albums = data 
// console.log(data) returns data )); 
});

console.log(albums); // returns undefined?
```

Note: when I fetch the data from the API I get the data in my data variable. When I console log on it, it returns an array with 3 rows.

But when I want to write my data value to the albums variable it gets undefined when I call the console.log at the last row of the script. What am I doing wrong? I'm kinda stuck because I really don't know where the problem is.

**Edit:**

Based on the comments I managed to fix the issue.

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  let albums;
  let hasData;

  onMount(async () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/albums/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        albums = data;
        hasData = true;
      });
  });
</script>

{#if hasData}
  {#each Object.values(albums) as album}
    {album.title}
  {:else}
    <p>Loading...</p>
  {/each}
{/if}
```

Comment: please use it as reactive like this $: console.log(albums);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your promise code. Also, the `console.log()` statement is executed before the response from your API comes back from the server. Maybe it's advisable for you to learn more about asynchronous code because it can be tricky to understand.

In principle, your code looks similar to the example about `onmount`. So using it for reference might help you:
https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount

You can debug by rendering your variable into the DOM/HMTL. Because the contents of objects are not directly converted to readable strings you can use `JSON.stringify()` for debugging. Also, check out the network tab for debugging API requests and responses.

```js
    <script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let albums = [];

    onMount(async () => { 
        fetch("/tutorial/api/album")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                albums = data
            })
        // console.log(data) returns data )); 
    });
    
    </script>

    <h1>{JSON.stringify(albums)}}</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me. Didn't notice the syntax error. Also thankyou for pointing out the network tab, this really helps aswell. I'm trying to display the titles of the album now with the {#each}. Hopefully I will get this down with your help.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch is async so `console.log(albums);` executes before you get the response from your api.

Comment: Thankyou but how do I know what's inside of my variable? Second thing is when I add `{#each albums as album}
  {album.title}
{/each}
`
to the file I get the following error: 
`Uncaught Error: {#each} only iterates over array-like objects.`
Makes me think my API doesn't return the right array structure. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I provided you with some tips about debugging in my answer

Comment: Your json looks fine. According to the documentation @TobiObeck mentioned `{#each}` has an `{:else}` block to render something while the variable is empty. Like this: `{#each albums as album} {album.title} {:else} loading... {/each}`